# How do I create a wide ag-grid without clipping or scrolling?

Tags: ag-grid

How do I make an ag-grid instance of arbitrary width, as determined by columns, without horizontal scrolling (on the element) and without clipping?

So, if I have 20 columns averaging 100 pixels wide, then the grid is 2000 pixels wide (and will make the BROWSER horizontal scroll appear). The grid will not have its own horizontal scroll and will not be clipped to whatever the browser width is.